# How to repeat specific numbers in while loop and append them as numeric in R

Tags: r, loops, while-loop, append, repeat

I was wondering if someone help me to solve my problem. I want to produce numbers times if I have a number more than 10. For example, if I want to write simple code:

```
    n= 53 
mem = rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),times=c(10,10,10,10,10,3))
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5  
[50] 5 6 6 6 

n= 52
mem = rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),times=c(10,10,10,10,10,2)) 
 
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5  
[50] 5 6 6
```

#To produce the numbers with specific repetition, I wrote the While loop. however, it #works for 50 or 60 not for 53 or 62. and it doesn't append it. Thanks in advance.
#The code is here:

```
n=53
x= rep(c(), times= c())
num=0
while (n>10) {
  n=n-10
  num=num+1
  x= rep(c(num), times= c(10))
  n=n+1
  x= rep(c(num), times= c(10))
  print(x)
  df <- rbind(df,as.numeric(x))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can add `rep` for the `times` as well

```
n <- 52
rep(1:6, times = rep(c(10, 2), c(5, 1)))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6

n <- 53
rep(1:6, times = rep(c(10, 3), c(5, 1)))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6
```

Comment: Thanks for you code.However, I wrote the while loop because n is always changing. there are random numbers,  may be there are 100, 97, 37, 79 so on.

Comment: I solved my problem, it was in the process of appending          
 n=103
num=1
mem <- vector()

while (n>10) {
  
  x= rep(c(num), times= c(10))
  
  n=n-10
  
  num=num+1
  
  mem <- append(mem, x)
  
}

x= rep(c(num), times= c(n))

mem <- append(mem, x)

print(mem)